# Attaching a file

Tags: excel, vba, macos, email, outlook

The idea is to attach an Excel file using `Attachment.Add`.

A macro reads the files within a folder and displays it in a column. I would like to attach those files via Excel.

I get an error on

```
.Attachments.Add Filelist & "\" & "Attch"
```

```vb
Sub Sendemailusingword()

    Dim Olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim Olemail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olmail As Object
    Dim olinsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wddoc As Word.Document
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Filelist As String
    Dim Attch As String
    x = 1
    row_number = 7
    count = Sheet1.Range("K1")
    
    For x = 1 To count
        row_number = row_number + 1
        
        Attch = Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number).Value
        Filelist = "K:\3SHARE\2016 Plan\Statment Email Send"
        
        Set Olapp = New Outlook.Application
        Set Olemail = Olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
              
        With Olemail
            .Display
            .To = Sheet1.Range("G" & row_number)
            .Subject = Sheet1.Range("D6") & Sheet1.Range("F" & row_number)
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "ComdataCommissions@comdata.com"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .CC = Sheet1.Range("H" & row_number) & ";" & Sheet1.Range("I" & row_number)
         
            Set olinsp = .GetInspector
            Set wddoc = olinsp.WordEditor
                  
            Sheet1.Activate
            Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Copy
            
            wddoc.Range.Paste
            .Attachments.Add Filelist & "\" & "Attch"
            
        End With
    Next x
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the quotation marks `"` from attch try `& Attch`

Answer (score 1):

```
.Attachments.Add Filelist & "\" & Attch
```

Assuming the variable Attch contains the filename of the file to be attached.

EDIT: noticed you tagged with <kbd>excel-vba-mac</kbd>, in which case I don't think backslash will work as a path separator.  `:` or maybe `/` should work, or use `Application.PathSeparator`